# How to convert JSON to CSV using python

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv

I have a JSON file around 120Mb, I tried converting the JSON file to CSV by running a python script

code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path =r'D:\filename.json'
read_file = pd.read_json (file_path)
export_file_path = r'D:\output.csv'
read_file.to_csv (export_file_path, index = None, header=True)
```

The JSON file looks like this

```
[{"dateTime": "2019-11-01 00:00:05", "value": {"bpm": 54, "confidence": 3}}, {"dateTime": "2019-11-01 00:00:10", "value": {"bpm": 52, "confidence": 3}}..........
```

The CSV File looks like this

[image]

How can I get only the bpm values and also I want to remove the confidence values

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a dataframe from the JSON file
It will have three columns: dateTime, bpm and confidence
then df = df.drop(columns=['confidence'])

Then use df.to_csv